# Is it necessary to specify content-type in http response header?

Tags: css, javascript, http-headers

Except for the html document, currently all the files (css, javascript and images) served from my web server do not specify the `content-type` in the http response header. I happen to notice this as I intend to remove the `type` attribute in both my `script` tag and `link` tag, but came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364746) which says the following:

> The MIME type is also sent via the HTTP Content-Type header, so using
>   type="text/css" would only be extra bytes.

Comment: I believe you need to specify Content-Type for scripts to execute in IE. This is to prevent malicious users uploading scripts to image sharing websites.

Comment: @Brendon, thanks for pointing out the security implication. Is there any other aspect worth noting, security-wise, assuming no user uploaded content?

Comment: Are you sure your _server_ is not sending a `Content-Type` header for these files? If you are viewing the response from files served from your _browser cache_ then you probably won't see a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Most servers will send the correct mime types by default, so unless you explicitly set your server to not send it, I'm betting the files *are* being sent with the correct mime type.

Comment: @w3d, thanks for your comment. I realize after rechecking that what I am reading off is actually from the request header of a `304 not modified` file. Not exactly the cache, but the content-type is dropped from the header. Disabling the cache, everything appears normal again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**. By the HTTP protocol, [clause 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1):

> “Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the resource.”

So yes, the response headers should contain `Content-Type` header for any response data (called “entity-body” in the protocol, often “file” in common language). If it is omitted, the browser is allowed to make its own wild guesses on the type of data it got. In many contexts, the risk of wrong guesses is negligible, but this not a good excuse for violating the protocol.

Attributes like `type=text/css` and `type=text/javascript` have not been necessary, except by some formal specifications, or even useful. Even if a server incorrectly sends e.g. CSS data without `Content-Type`, browsers will treat the data as CSS if `<link rel=stylesheet ...>` was the element that caused the request. It’s the `rel` attribute that matters in that case.